# how to get highlight term in the json result and save in into list? java

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "relevant": ["Lighthouse", "family", "house", "national Ranking", "national Years", "national Selection", "carbohydrate", "national Affiliation", "home Arena", "temp Place"],
    "result": [{
        "keyword": "And thank people mission American Homeland Department Security White Applause",
        "Sentence": "At the White House he has done an outstanding job.",
        "highlightTerm": ["house"]
    }, {
        "keyword": "And thank people mission American Homeland Department Security White Applause",
        "Sentence": "Welcome to the White House and welcome to this historic moment.",
        "highlightTerm": ["house","family"]

    }]
}
```

I would like to parser the JSON result to get all the highlightTerm and save it into  ArrayList.

as the "highlightTerm": ["house","family"] is not a string, how to parse it???

```
   JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
     System.out.println("result is:: " + result);

      ArrayList<String> highlightTermlist = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i =0; i < result.length(); i++){

         // String Sentence = result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Sentence");

      JSONObject j = result.getJSONObject(i);
  System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj:: " + j);
```

error:

```
 ArrayList<String> highlightTermlist =result.getJSONObject(i).getArrayList("highlightTermlist");
```

Comment: Try `getJSONArray("highlightTerm")`.

Comment: yes, i can get the individual highlightTerm, then how to combine all the highlightTerm into following format ["house","house","family"]???@shmosel

Comment: You can manually slog through the JSONParser, but if you find yourself doing stuff like this a lot, maybe something like https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath would be much less boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

You have get as a Json Array and loop through it.

Try with the below code.. it gives result as

> Complete HighlightTerms list --[family, house]

converting the list to Json Object with JsonArray element, as below.

> {"highlightTerm":["house","house","family"]}

If you want duplicate values as well, change from Set to list.

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

 List<String> allHighlightItems = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "sample.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray results = (JSONArray)(jsonObject.get("result"));
        System.out.println("Complete Data list --"+results.toString());

        for(Object singleResult : results) {
            JSONObject singleArrayData = (JSONObject) singleResult;
            JSONArray highlightTermOfGivenResult = (JSONArray)singleArrayData.get("highlightTerm");
            for(Object singleHighlightTerm: highlightTermOfGivenResult){
                if(singleHighlightTerm != null) {
                    allHighlightItems.add(singleHighlightTerm.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Complete HighlightTerms list --"+allHighlightItems.toString());

        JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        myJsonObject.put("highlightTerm",allHighlightItems);

        System.out.println("Complete HighlightTerms list --"+myJsonObject.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```